# How to save a random number, just one time, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory

I tried to save a random number, just one time in J.

```js
let Machine = {
    position : 0,
    num_move : 0,
    isEmpty : true,
    memory : [],
    start : function () {
        for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            this.memory.push({move:undefined,isEmpty: true})
        }
    },
    generateMove:function () {
        let num = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1)
        if (num>=10) {
            num-=1
        }
        return num
    },
    // Update move
    move : function () {
        let move = this.generateMove()
        let prev = this.num_move
        if (!this.memory[this.num_move] && this.num_move<=0) {
            this.memory[this.num_move]=move
            this.num_move+=1
        }
    },
    //Return data values
    data : function () {
        return {
            memory : this.memory,
            num_move : this.num_move
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is Javascript save a new random number, but i just want to save it once. Like a memory.

```js
Machine.move() //First time
console.log(Machine.data())
// {memory : [2], num_move : 1}
Machine.move() //Second time
console.log(Mahine.data())
// {memory : [9], num_move : 1}
```

I also tried initialize the Machine Object with start method. And change move method like this. To check if is Empty, before push memory

```js
move : function () {
        let move = this.generateMove()
        if (this.memory[this.num_move].isEmpty) {
            this.memory[this.num_move].isEmpty = false
            this.memory[this.num_move].move=move
            this.num_move+=1
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work. JS generate a new random number ever whenever i call from console.

Comment: I think your problem is `this.num_move<=0`. Are you sure you want add a new element when only when `num_move` is less than or equal to 0? Also, I think you can instead use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on the array rather than an entire `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I just try it and save the object and got the same result in both turns.

```js
let Machine = {
    position : 0,
    num_move : 0,
    isEmpty : true,
    memory : [],
    start : function () {
        for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            this.memory.push({move:undefined,isEmpty: true})
        }
    },
    generateMove:function () {
        let num = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1)
        if (num>=10) {
            num-=1
        }
        return num
    },
    // Update move
    move : function () {
        let move = this.generateMove()
        let prev = this.num_move
        if (!this.memory[this.num_move] && this.num_move<=0) {
            this.memory[this.num_move]=move
            this.num_move+=1
        }
    },
    //Return data values
    data : function () {
        return {
          memory : this.memory,
          num_move : this.num_move
        }
    }
}


var obj = Object.create(Machine);

obj.move();
console.log(obj.data());
// {memory : [2], num_move : 1}

obj.move();
console.log(obj.data());
// {memory : [2], num_move : 1}
```